# How to move the navigation bar outside the UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, uistoryboard

I'm very new to Swift and I'm just learning UICollectionView. I converted my UITableView to UICollectionView. The Navigation Bar in the UITableView is showing correctly on top but for the UICollectionView, I couldn't drag the it outside the cell to be just under "Collection View."

I can drag it down the First Responder or Exit but it would be outside of the view. When I try to drag the Navigation Bar of the Table View, it would no longer allow me to drag it back to its current position and only allow me to drag inside the cell.

I don't know what I did incorrectly here. I use "Show" to present the view and that's what I used before for my UITableView too. Please let me know if I need to provide other details. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Actually, it seems that the Navigation Bar is set up inside the Table view. (Between `TableView` and `TableViewCell`). For the Collection View, you can remove the `NavigationBar` inside the cell first. Then, try to drag a `Navigation Item` to the controller, instead of a `NavigationBar`.

Comment: I removed the `NavigationBar` and added `NavigationItem` but I can only drag it to the same place where `NavigationBar` can be dragged to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have to :

- remove this navigation bar
- select your CollectionViewController
- go to Editor => Embed in => Navigation controller

This should embed your collection view controller in a Navigation controller and set the navigation bar correctly.

Hopefully this helps

Comment: Embedding it to the `NavigationController` worked but it creates a problem because I have a `prepareForSegue` function that has the `CollectionView` as the destination. Or is there a way to jump over the NavigationController when doing segue?

Comment: Sure you can ! If the destination VC is supposed to be embed in a navigation controller you proceed just the same. If not (example: a modal popover) you can just set a push segue

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks so much. I managed to correct all the segues and I was wondering if there's a way to change the transition animation to "slide down" because it slides up when I present it modally but there's no option to make it slide down to return to the root controller. Lastly, why is it that I need a navigation controller for this collection view when I didn't need one when I created the table view controller? Although the table view controller has turned like this as well.